# Helm upgrade chart and reuse values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm confused when to use `reuse-values` option while upgrading a helm chart

As I know that `reuse-values: reuse the last release's values and merge in any overrides from the command line via --set and -f`, but when I use it when upgrading chart, for example, **"stable/elasticsearch-curator"** the upgrade fails due to `UPGRADE FAILED Error: CronJob.batch "es-curator-elasticsearch-curator" is invalid: spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", "Never" Error: UPGRADE FAILED: CronJob.batch "es-curator-elasticsearch-curator" is invalid: spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", "Never"`

So, when do I use it and when should I don't? and what is the effect of not using it while upgrading?

Comment: the problem looks to be in `.Values.cronjob.jobRestartPolicy` that you are passing. Are you overriding it somehow ?

Comment: I know, but simply used the following command "helm upgrade --install es-curator stable/elasticsearch-curator --reuse-values", I think it is from an old chart version